# What would be a better approach to multiple 'elseif' in an if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently developing a PhoneGap application. I have a rather large if/else statement that simply compares strings to a JSON from an API response.  What is the best approach to reducing the code and making it more efficient? Please see code below:

Code:

```
current = JSON.stringify( value.main ).replace(/['"]+/g, ''); 

    // strings to compare to currerent weather conditions
    var stringSnow = "Snow";
    var stringRain = "Rain";
    var stringFog = "Fog"
    var stringMist = "Mist";
    var stringClear = "Clear";
    var stringClouds = "Clouds";
    var stringHaze = "Haze";

    // Update homescreen background
    if (stringSnow === current)
    {
      // console.log("Its Snowing");
       $('body').css('background-image', 'url(assets/weatherBG/wall_snow.jpg)');
    } 
    else if (stringRain === current)
    {  
      //console.log("its raining");
      $('body').css('background-image', 'url(assets/weatherBG/wall_rain.jpg)');
    }
    else if (stringMist === current)
    {  
      //console.log("its mist");
      $('body').css('background-image', 'url(assets/weatherBG/wall_fog.jpg)');
    }
    else if (stringFog === current)
    {  
      //console.log("its Foggy");
      $('body').css('background-image', 'url(assets/weatherBG/wall_fog.jpg)');
    }
    else if (stringClear === current)
    {  
      //console.log("its clear");
      $('body').css('background-image', 'url(assets/weatherBG/wall_clear.jpg)');
    }
    else if (stringClouds === current)
    {  
      //console.log("its Cloudy");
      $('body').css('background-image', 'url(assets/weatherBG/wall_cloudy.jpg)');
    }
    else if (stringHaze === current)
    {
      //console.log("its hazy");
      $('body').css('background-image', 'url(assets/weatherBG/wall_cloudy.jpg)')
    }
```

Comment: a switch statement or lookup table.

Comment: `images = {"snow": "assets/weatherBG/wall_snow.jpg"...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the alternative to use multiple else/if-statements is to use a switch. This language construct is only usable for "simple" checks, like for your use case.

You can use it like following:

```
switch(current) {
   case 'Snow':
       $("body").css("background-image", "url(assets/weatherBG/wall_snow.jpg)");
      break;
   // ...

   default:
        // Else block
      break;
}
```

Also think about creating a helper function for the template url like this:

```
createBackgroundUrl(imageName) {
    return `url(assets/weatherBG/${imageName})` 
}
```

The function will help you reduce redundancy and improve readablity like following:

```
var backgroundUrl = "";
switch(current) {
   case 'Snow':
      backgroundUrl = createBackgroundUrl("wall_snow.jpg");
      break;
   // ...

   default:
        // Else block
      break;
}

$("body").css("background-image", backgroundUrl)
```

Hopefully this will help you, happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a lookup table:

```
var backgrounds = {
    Snow: "wall_snow.jpg",
    Rain: "wall_rain.jpg",
    // ...
};
```

then

```
var url = backgrounds[current] || "default.jpg";
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(assets/weatherBG/' + url + ')');
```

In situations where a lookup table wouldn't work, a `switch` statement is sometimes a good choice. In JavaScript, `switch` is exactly like `if`/`else` with `===` comparisons, just with different syntax (case labels can even be expressions).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a key then pass the current into that object like so

```js
current = 'snow';
// strngs to compare to currerent weather conditions
const options = {
  snow: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
  rain: 'http://via.placeholder.com/450x250'
}

// you can added your base path after url or added it in the key 
// if changes between images
$('body').css('background-image', `url(${options[current]})`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about switch statements?

```
let image;

switch(current){
  case "Snow":
    image = "url(assets/weatherBG/wall_snow.jpg)";
    break;
  case "Rain":
    image = "url(assets/weatherBG/wall_rain.jpg)";
    break;
  // handle other cases like: Fog, Mist, Clear, Clouds, Haze in the same way

  default: 
    image = "url(assets/weatherBG/nothing.jpg)"
}

$("body").css("background-image", image);
```